# How to use request without AppCompatActivity

Tags: android, kotlin

I want to make and use class that only containing permission-related features. (IDK how to explain it, group of function to use permission)

I want that `class` does not use `AppCompatActivity`

So I made it poorly, and it works!
But I think using `AppCompatActivity` as argument is... maybe not good architecture. (I know it is not my level now. but I want to think about it for my code)

I tried to find how to use ActivityCompat.requestPermissions() without AppCompatActivity

- MY_PERMISSION (per_type) is enum

I'm user of C++ before... sorry for my code style T0T... I will fix it soon

```
class PermissionFunc
(It does not have any other class, inheritance, implements, extends(?))
{
... (skip)


private fun checkPermission(appCompactActivity: AppCompatActivity, per_type: MY_PERMISSION): Boolean
{
    var bReady = false

    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(appCompactActivity, callGetTypeString(per_type))
                                                        != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
    {
        //퍼미션을 보유중이지 않을 경우
        //알림창을 별도로 띄워준다.
        //If it does not have permission, popup dialog
        GeneralFunc()
            .CallCreateAlertDialog(appCompactActivity, appCompactActivity.getString(R.string.TEXT_NOTICE),
                appCompactActivity.getString(R.string.TEXT_PERMISSION_NOTICE, getPermissionName(per_type)),
            false, per_type)
    }
    else
    {
        bReady = true
    }

    return bReady
}
```

---

```
private fun CreateAlertDialog(appCompactActivity: AppCompatActivity, s_dialog_title : String,
                              s_dialog_message : String, add_negative_btn : Boolean = false,
                              per_type: MY_PERMISSION = MY_PERMISSION.E_NONE
)
{
    var str_title = s_dialog_title
    var str_message = s_dialog_message
    val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(appCompactActivity)

    if(str_title.isNullOrEmpty()||str_message.isNullOrEmpty())
    {
        return
    }

    builder.setTitle(str_title)
    builder.setMessage(str_message)
    builder.setCancelable(false)

    //per_type가 비어있지 않다면 퍼미션 요청용 Dialog이다.
    //if per_type is not empty, it is for permission
    if(per_type != MY_PERMISSION.E_NONE)
    {
        //popup dialog. if it receive btn OK -> request permission
        //요청 팝업을 띄워준다. 버튼을 누르면 리퀘스트.
        builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.BTN_OK)
        {
                dialogInterface, i -> PermissionFunc()
            .callRequestPermission(appCompactActivity, per_type)
        }
    }
    else
    {
        builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.BTN_OK)
        {
                dialogInterface, i -> dialogInterface.cancel()
        }
    }


    if(add_negative_btn)
    {
        builder.setNegativeButton(R.string.BTN_CANCEL)
        {
                dialogInterface, i -> dialogInterface.cancel()
        }
    }

    val dialog = builder.create()
    dialog.show()
}
```

---

```
private fun requestPermission(appCompactActivity: AppCompatActivity, per_type: MY_PERMISSION)
{
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(appCompactActivity,
        arrayOf(callGetTypeString(per_type)), callGetTypeCode(per_type))
}
```

...(skip)
}

It doesn't have err, but I want to Improve my code.

Comment: use Activity instead of ContextCompat !

Comment: T0T) I search it by your comment, but I couldn't find using requestPermission without activities.. I want to use it at class that inheritance service. So I don't have AppCompatActivity as argument

Comment: Permission request dialog itself is actually a transparent `Activity` that's started for result and that result is returned to `onPermissionResult` of calling `Activity`. It's impossible to request permissions directly from non-activity context, closest you can get is force starting a transparent activity and using it for that purpose.

Comment: Oh... that was problem... thank you. umm... then, if I don't use a dialog, is it can working without activity?